# jquery find by attr and change parent

Tags: jquery, find, parent, addclass

I want to change the class of the parent element that is found by the find method of jquery:

```
$("#navi").find("a[href='" + ultiparent + "']").addClass("active");
```

works, but the result is `<a class="active" href="blub">`

```
$("#navi").find("a[href='" + ultiparent + "']").parent().addClass("active");
```

does not work!

I need `<li class="active"><a href="blub">`

Thank you!

Comment: Posting the HTML sure would help ?

Comment: That looks to me like it should work. Can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Your code perfectly works in our view :) http://jsfiddle.net/n4gf6qve/ I think you must have been doing something wrong like with html or ready handler.....

Comment: As other's have said, don't post an answer to provide more information. Push the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25771526/edit) to add stuff to your question.

Comment: I'm really sorry! I was very confused last night and this was my second post here! Your examples are working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

onClick of link get the href and add class to parent li

**JS**

```
$("ul li a").click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var a = $(this).attr("href")
    $("ul li").removeClass("active")
    $(this).parents("li").addClass("active")
    alert(a)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/5umm5aee/